# on changing device font, Font sizes changes and overflow on another component

Tags: reactjs, react-native, fonts, font-size, styling

I'm working on react native ,
On changing my device font size my app font size also changes, I know i can restrict them not to change but requirement is increaase font size at certain limit.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function that takes the actual fontSize and controls it

```
import { PixelRatio } from 'react-native';

function getFontSize(size) {
  const maxSize = 18; //Your max size
  const deviceScale = PixelRatio.getFontScale(); 

  const scaled = size * deviceScale;

  return scaled > maxSize ? maxSize : scaled;
};
```